# I'd like to get the value of a slider control via Python script

Tags: javascript, python, arduino

I'm working on a little Arduino Project and I've got a problem. I need to get the value of a Range Slider from a local Website to the analog (PWM) output of the Arduino.

I have found an example where you can switch a LED on and off via browser but i can't think of a way to make it work for integer input instead of boolean...

This is the Javascript of the example:

```
function controlLed(turnOn) {
session.call("com.myapp.mcu.control_led", [turnOn]);
     }
```

and this is what the Python script says:

```
def controlLed(self, turnOn):

  """This method is exported as RPC and can be called by connected clients"""
  if turnOn:
     payload = b'1'
  else:
     payload = b'0'
  if self.debug:
     print("Serial TX: {0}".format(payload))
  self.transport.write(payload)
```

and this are the buttons of the web site:

`<button onclick="controlLed(false)">LED Off</button>
 <button onclick="controlLed(true)">LED On</button>`

It would be really nice if someone could help me.